# Seriously struggling with sdist - Want to be able to skip folder when importing

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, pip, python-packaging

Package structure:

```
main
|-folder1
   |- folderA
      |-myfile1.py
      |-myfile2.py
   |- folderB
      |-myfile3.py
      |-myfile4.py
|-folder2
   |-myfile5.py
|-setup.py
```

Right now I have to do this: `from main.folder1.folderA import myfile1`. What I want to be able to do is this:`from main.folderA import myfile1`
I am having the worst time with this.

It creates the correct folder structure in the build/ folder if I do `python3 setup.py build`, but it doesn't seem to work when I do `python3 setup.py sdist`.

My setup.py file looks like this:

```py
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

def find_packages_with_names():
    dict_of_packages = {}
    for pack in find_packages():
        location = pack.replace('.', '/')
        dict_of_packages[pack] = location
        if 'main.folder1.' in pack:
            new_name = pack.replace('.folder1.', '.')
            dict_of_packages[new_name] = location

    return dict_of_packages

setup(
    name="main"
    packages=find_packages_with_names().keys(),
    package_dir=find_packages_with_names(),
)
```

To potentially add confusion, it lets me `from main.folderA import myfile1` if I do this locally

```sh
pip3 install -v git+ssh://git@gitlab.com/path/repo-name.git@branch-name
```

However, it throws an error if I `from main.folderA import myfile1` after I run this in Docker

```
RUN --mount=type=ssh pip3 install -v git+ssh://git@gitlab.com/path/repo-name.git@branch-name
```

Questions:
1) Do I need to do sdist? It doesn't seem to pip install correctly if I just do build. If I can just use build that would be great!
2) Essentially any advice you can give me so that I can `python3 from main.folderA import myfile1` instead of `python3 from main.folder1.folderA import myfile1` would be amazing!

Thanks in advance + hope you are all staying healthy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the answer even though this has taken a little piece of forever to figure out.

```sh
python3 setup.py bdist_wheel
```